# Clearing an Array C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a list as

```
string[] names = new string[20000];
```

I need to clear the items in this list.
I tried `names.clear()` , `names.Dispose()` but none seems to be appropriate.

What shud I have used ?

Comment: What do you mean they are not appropriate? What is it that clear() and Dispose() are not doing?

Comment: `names = null; names = new string[2000];` ?

Comment: names = new string[];

Comment: question name is quite misleading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Array.Clear(names, 0, names.Length);
```

have you tried this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, i think the best approach is to actually change array to `List` if the list is what you need:

```
var names = new List<string>();
```

You can then clear it using `names.Clear()`

Comment: That's wasteful ... clear the array like other answers sounds much better

Comment: @Noctis, I disagree. What looks like a waste to me is creating a 20000-element string array. I bet the only reason for that is OP's inability to tell which size he actually needs. `List` solves that problem in more elegant way.

Comment: Yep, but we're not guessing he's reasoning here :) we're trying to help. Seems he got he's answer anyways by now.

Comment: @Noctis, yes, i understood what you meant. You are implying that answers, which suggest changing approach instead of solving the problem at hand are not helpful. As i said: i disagree. :)

Comment: Let's agree to disagree. I'll suggest changing approaches sometimes as well ...hopefully, this is where we'll stop disagreeing :)

Answer (score 2):

That is an `array` not a `list`. Try [`Array.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Array.Clear(names, 0, names.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
names = new string[20000];
```